# How to search for typical files in Windows Phone?

Tags: functionality, search, file-format

All of we know how to search for a typical file in Windows OS for PC's,Tablets etc. using '**`*.format`**' . If we want search mp3 files in a folder, we just use '***.mp3**' .Like that , is it possible to search in Windows Phones using any application(s)?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no file extension search, only filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) app to browse and search your files. However, no need to use wildcards; it will find your content without them.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use `.mp3` instead of `*.mp3` in this app. Just to make it clear. More than that, if there is a file with a name like `amp3rsand.txt` it will get it too.

Comment: You're right! Updated my answer.